# en Python , método llamado distancia, que tome otro punto y calcule la distancia entre los dos puntos y la muestre por pantalla

Tags: python-3.x

Añade un método llamado distancia, que tome otro punto y calcule la distancia entre los dos puntos y la muestre por pantalla. La fórmula es la siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Punto:
    x=0
    y=0
    
       
       
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print("estoy en el constructor de Punto")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "(X={},Y={})".format(self.x, self.y)
    
    def cuadrante(self, x, y ):
        if x>0 and y>0:
            print("pertenece a Cuadrante I")
        elif x<0 and y>0:
            print("pertenece a Cuadrante II")
        elif x<0 and y<0:
            print("pertenece a Cuadrante III")
        elif x>0 and y<0:
            print("pertenece a Cuadrante IV")
        elif x== 0 and y==0:
            print("ORIGEN")            
            print("entramos en cuadrante")

    def vector(self, p):
        print("El vector entre {} y {} es ({}, {})".format(self, p, p.x - self.x, p.y - self.y) )
**el codigo hasta aqui funciona, apartir de distancia me da SyntaxError: invalid syntax****texto en negrita** 
    import math
    def distancia(self,t):
        print("La distancia entre {} y {} es: ({}, {}) ".format(self, t, math.sqrt(( t.x - self.x)**2 + (t.y - self.y)**2)) 
        
print (P)      
A = Punto(2,3)
B = Punto(5,5)
A.vector(B)
```

**por favor ayuda , mi metodo distancia no se si es del todo correcto y donde puede mejorar para realizar su funcion**

---

**he cambiado el planteamiento del problema y me ha funcionado de la siguiente manera:**
**empiezo importando math para luego usar su funcion sqrt, le doy dos atributos (P1,P2) que uso en la formula para calcular la distancias entre estos dos puntos.**

```
import math
class Punto:
    x=0
    y=0
    
       
       
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print("estoy en el constructor de Punto")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "(X={},Y={})".format(self.x, self.y)
    
    def cuadrante(self, x, y ):
        if x>0 and y>0:
            print("pertenece a Cuadrante I")
        elif x<0 and y>0:
            print("pertenece a Cuadrante II")
        elif x<0 and y<0:
            print("pertenece a Cuadrante III")
        elif x>0 and y<0:
            print("pertenece a Cuadrante IV")
        elif x== 0 and y==0:
            print("ORIGEN")            
            print("entramos en cuadrante")
    def vector(self, p):
        print("El vector entre {} y {} es ({}, {})".format(self, p, p.x - self.x, p.y - self.y) )
    
    def distancia(p1 , p2):
        print("La distancia es:", math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)**2 + (p1.y-p2.y)**2)) 

print("="*40)

A = Punto(2,3)
B = Punto(5,5)
A.vector(B)
A.distancia(B)        
print("*"*50)

C= Punto(7,-4)
D= Punto(-9,8)
C.vector(D)
C.distancia(D)
```

---

**y obtengo el resultado pedido**

========================================
estoy en el constructor de Punto
estoy en el constructor de Punto
El vector entre (X=2,Y=3) y (X=5,Y=5) es (3, 2)
La distancia es: 3.605551275463989

---

estoy en el constructor de Punto
estoy en el constructor de Punto
El vector entre (X=7,Y=-4) y (X=-9,Y=8) es (-16, 12)
La distancia es: 20.0

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], considera editar y explicar un poco mejor el problema que tienes con tu código actual

Comment: tengo que construir un metodo que se llame distancia y calcule la distancia entre un punto A=(X1,Y1) y un punto B=(X2,Y2). Con la correspondiente formula que he dejado en la imagen arriba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero te sirva, saludos

```
def Distancia():
    #Calcular distancia y mostrar por pantalla
    print("La distancia es:", math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)**2 + (p1.y-p2.y)**2))
```

adicional a esto puedes aproximarle a un entero aniadiendo int(#todo el resultado)

Comment: Perfecto, funcionando muchas gracias.